# Some thoughts about TeX.StackExchange

Tags: discussion, community

To begin with, this is not a real question, so probably it will soon be removed by our moderators, but I'm writing it anyways.

The day after tomorrow will be one year since I registered to TeX.StackExchange. My profile page today says "Visited 365 days, 365 consecutive" (but this is a leap year), and [my first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/how-can-i-provide-a-verbatim-unescaped-commandline-for-executing-with-write18/14200#14200) was on March 24, 2011.

In this year I've been quite active on the site and, judging from the results, this activity has pleased many members of the community: my current reputation count is 75018, which makes for an average of 205.5 reputation per day. I won't hide the fact that I'm quite proud of being the top user for reputation, but this wouldn't be without the continuous supply of interesting questions.

However, the main reason why it's nice to always have a browser window open on it is the warm and friendly atmosphere of the site. So I want to thank everybody for this wonderful year: our moderators Stefan Kottwitz, Martin Scharrer and Joseph Wright (a special thank to Joseph for his support in learning LaTeX3 secrets) and all the people who always contribute interesting questions and answers: I believe to have learned very much from the expertise of Herbert, Ulrike Fischer, Frank Mittelbach, David Carlisle, lockstep, Audrey, Jake, Werner, Alan Munn and Bruno Le Floch (to mention a few, I apologize for not being able to make a complete list), but also from the questions: as a mathematician I know that without problems to solve the knowledge doesn't improve.

Of course a special thank goes to Paulo Cereda, without whom the chat and the site wouldn't be as they are.

Comment: I've learnt a great deal from reading your answers (and everyone elses', including the people you mentioned), and second all of your comments about the friendliness and warmness of the site- long live tex exchange!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oh my, I really don't know what to say. `:)`

`TeX.sx` wouldn't be the same without you.

Thanks for sharing your knowlegde with the community. Thanks for sharing your wisdom. Thanks for making `TeX.sx` a better place. Thanks for being here in every moment.

You are a great friend. A true friend. Grazie mille, Enrico.

[image: Lion]

*Chi trova un amico trova un tesoro.*

Comment: I can see you have a whole range of wardrobe options for that lion.. and expressions that are not that murderous (though a bit mischievous.) :)